# TextView real time update AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm making an android application that downloads some text from a web page and puts it in a `String`, then it prints the string in a `TextView`. But the content of the web page can change every seconds, so i want `TextView` to update in real-time, showing the new `String` every seconds. To download text from the webpage and set `TextView`'s text I used `AsyncTask`, and i called the `execute()` in `onCreate()` method, in main `Activity`. I don't know how update it, without make application crashed.
Sorry for bad English, that's my MainActivity:

```
   package com.example.pack;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    TextView textView;
    URL url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        url = null;

        try
        {
            url = new URL("myURL");
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e) {}

        new VariabileLikeTask(textView).execute(url);
    }
    }
```

And that's my aSyncTask:

```
package com.example.pack;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class VariabileLikeTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, CharSequence>
{
    TextView textView;

    public VariabileLikeTask(TextView textView)
    {
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls)
    {
        URL url = urls[0];
        InputStream in = null;
        int risposta = -1;
        String text = "";

        try
        {
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
              throw new IOException("No connection");

            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            risposta = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if (risposta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            text = bf.readLine();

            in.close();
            bf.close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        return text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(CharSequence text)
    {
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Sorry if the format code is wrong, this is my first thread.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a bad idea to run the AsyncTask frequently? This will make the app heavier in network operations.

If you mean the word **real-time** push notification or socket connection would be the best match. If you can't use a push notification because you are trying to fetch data from a Web page consider using a service class. Then simply make a timer task and run the AsyncTask after a small interval of time.

Here a simple demo of running the task after an interval of time,

```
    private int m_interval = 5000; // 5 seconds by default, can be changed later
    private Handle m_handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
      ...
      m_handler = new Handler();
    }

    Runnable m_statusChecker = new Runnable()
    {
         @Override 
         public void run() {
              //this function can change value of m_interval.
              new VariabileLikeTask(textView).execute(url); 
              m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker, m_interval);
         }
    }

    void startRepeatingTask()
    {
        m_statusChecker.run(); 
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask()
    {
        m_handler.removeCallback(m_statusChecker);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441771/3996257) the user try to show dialog from AsyncTask, but the code it's the same to change txtBox in runtime, watch it!

Tell me if I helped you and good programming!