# Call method in another thread on completion

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am using firebase Realtime Database. Hence, my data changes come from another thread. Hence, I have no control on when the fresh data update comes over. How do I then know when to call to refresh my UI?

This is my implementation of a swipe to delete in a RecyclerView.

```
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        mListRoute.get(pos).removeRoute();
        refreshUI();
    }
```

This is the removeRoute() method found in my Route class

```
 public void removeRoute() {
        //Delete all the Route Instructions
        DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Routes")
                .child(routeId)
                .child("Route Instructions");

        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot routeInstruc : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    routeInstruc.getValue(RouteInstructions.class)
                            .removeRouteInstructions();
                }

                DatabaseReference mRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("Routes")
                        .child(routeId);
                mRef2.removeValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, the ***onDataChange()*** is called by another thread. Which means i do not know when to call my ***refreshUI()*** method.

I think i might be able to use a Looper but how do i fit that in the Route class?

Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, callbacks... Please show some code with an [edit]

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: You should use Interface for pupose

Comment: You can use event bus for communicating among threads. I suggests otto event bus (http://square.github.io/otto/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are **callbacks**.

**Callbacks** are practically mandatory when dealing with asynchronous calls, because when you call an asynchronous task, you are basically asking a worker thread to work for you.
It may take 1 second, 10 seconds, 10 minutes, etc, and you can not know for sure. What you can do is delegate that same worker thread and tell her "hey, reply back when you finish the task I gave you".
Enter the callbacks!

[You can check for more documentation regarding callbacks here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054720/what-is-callback-in-android)

Say that you have your *query defined with the ValueEventListener*

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {

   }
}
```

What you should do is **have a callback method that replies back as soon as the query listener** returns a value (in other words, when your query is executed).
So, have a method like ***'onResponseReceivedFromFirebase'*** and implement it on the callback

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // Implement your callback here with the parameters you want (for instance, I used a String there)
    public void onResponseReceivedFromFirebase(String argument){
        Log.d(MyActivity.class,argument);
    }

    ....

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
            onResponseReceivedFromFirebase("the response arrived!");
       }
    }

    ...

}
```

@Edit
Base on your updated code, I would proceed with the following

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot routeInstruc : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         routeInstruc.getValue(RouteInstructions.class)
        .removeRouteInstructions();
    }
    DatabaseReference mRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("Routes")
                    .child(routeId);
            mRef2.removeValue();
   // Implement the callback here 
   MyActivity.this.onResponseReceivedFromFirebase("We have received a response from   dataChanged");
}
```

@Edit 2 : **On Frank van Puffelen's remark, the onDataChange method already runs on the Main Thread**, thus allowing you to change any element on the UI.

Very import : **If the processing payload of the outcoming data is considerably large, you should pass that same processing into another thread (e.g. An AsyncTask) to avoid making your app non-responsive.**

Comment: *firebaser here* Great explanation. But note that the Firebase client already calls `onDataChange()` on the main thread. So introducing an `onResponseReceivedFromFirebase` is not needed, the UI can be updated straight from `onDataChange()`.

Comment: Yes, exactly! I knew it, but usually I recommend people to avoid doing the "process all the data right here & right now aftey" way of doing stuff. I've editted the answer based on your good observation!

Comment: With the Firebase SDK, I would recommend to do the updates in the callback *unless there is something unusually heavy* involved. Between Firebase and Glide, `AsyncTask`s are a rarity for me (I admit my apps are usually quite simple).

Answer (score 2):

While the Firebase client handles all network and disk IO on a separate thread, it invokes the callback to your code on the main thread. So you can update the UI straight from `onDataChange()`, without having to worry about the thread yourself.

In fact, all examples in the Firebase documentation update the UI from their `onDataChange()` (or `onChild...()`) callbacks. One [example from the database quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/PostDetailActivity.java#L86):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    mAuthorView.setText(post.author);
    mTitleView.setText(post.title);
    mBodyView.setText(post.body);
}
```

Comment: This would work,but i would have to enter the removeRoute() method in the Route.class file itself for easier management. Using the above method, i will need to copy the same method multiple times. Correct me if i am wrong. Still new to android programming. Thanks!

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen, is there a way to change the returning callback thread?