# Go back to main-thread inside coroutine?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

Im running this code since `addListenerForSingleEvent` is a long Running operation:

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {  
    userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                withContext(Main) {
                    toggleLoading()
                    val intent = Intent(this@LogInActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
            } else{
                withContext(Main) {
                    var addUsernameIntent = Intent(this@LogInActivity, 
                                             AddUsernameActivity::class.java)
                    startActivityForResult(addUsernameIntent, CHOOSE_USERNAME_REQUEST)
                }
            }
        }
   })
}
```

I get an error where i write `withContext(Main)` that says :

> Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

But I have a coroutine body right? Before i just had a `Thread(runnable {..})` instead of a couroutine, but i read that i shouldn't do intents inside any other Thread than main-thread so i changed to coroutine.

Comment: First, actually you are not using the IO coroutine at all! you are just adding a listener to `userRef` inside it which has nothing to do with IO. The implementation behind `userRef` defines how that function is called and tasks are performed.
Second, you are calling `withContext` inside `onDataChange` so it not in a courtine body.

Comment: All i really want to do is to run the run the listener on a separate thread, how can i do this? @MohammadOmidvar

Comment: First, check if it is not currently true (most listeners are invoked in the main thread).

Second, you can use traditional ways: `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post()` or `runOnUiThread`
Or if you want coroutines (which are based on the mentioned methods), you can use `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch()` as @commander-tvis said.

Comment: Why wrap that listener in a coroutine at all? It already runs on a background thread

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase client already runs any network and disk I/O operations on a separate thread. There almost never is a need to run `addListenerForSingleEvent` on a separate thread yourself.

Also see:

- [Do we need to use background thread for retrieving data using firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369433/do-we-need-to-use-background-thread-for-retrieving-data-using-firebase/39372597#39372597)
- [Firebase Android: onDataChange() event always executed in Main UI Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777400/firebase-android-ondatachange-event-always-executed-in-main-ui-thread/35777599#35777599)
- [Firebase database - run on different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878738/firebase-database-run-on-different-thread/39060380#39060380)
- [Call method in another thread on completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850777/call-method-in-another-thread-on-completion/38853093#38853093)

Answer (score 1):

Function of an anonymous object may capture the variables of the scope, but it is not in enclosing coroutine body. Replace `withContext(Main)` with creating a new coroutine: `<CoroutineScope>.launch(Main)`.

Comment: So i just do CoroutineScope(main).launch { } instead of withContext(Main)? Also when i try to print the current thread when i started first coroutine, it still prints out that it is the mainthread that it's running on

Comment: It is not very a good solution to create a new scope for each coroutine, you can share it and if you are working with Android UI, consider using `MainScope()`. Coroutines are scheduled to threads automatically, however you may influence it by creating your own dispatchers.

Comment: So i'm not sure i understand, can i write MainScope().launch {...} instead of withContext(Main)? I still don't get why it prints Main when i print name of current thread inside the coroutine

Comment: MainScope() can be stored

Comment: `MainScope` should be used is a delegate: `class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope by MainScope()`. Check the documentation on [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/)