# Why onCreate() method is a Callback Method in Android programming?

Tags: java, android, methods, callback, oncreate

I am a novice but I have already read [What is callback in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054720/what-is-callback-in-android) and [How to define callbacks in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android).

I think that I got the point in this kind of examples:
`button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        // my code
    }
});`

In many books I have found that methods used for managing the life cycle of the Activity (such as *protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState))* are defined as **Callback Methods**.

Why *onCreate()* is a Callback Method? Which is the function passed as an argument?
I have a Bundle as an argument, I don't see any *Interface* or *function* used as an argument.

Comment: "Why onCreate() is a Callback Method?" -- because our activity is being called into from an outside party, in this case some framework code. "I think that I got the point in this kind of examples" -- that is simply one way of registering a callback, for a narrow role (respond to a click event).

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, the second part is very clear. I will edit the question in order to talk about the first part of your answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare finally I have understood what you told in the first part. In my mind I had only a strict definition of "callback" and with that belief I couldn't get the point. Comments at this link [What is a callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function) helped me a lot.

Comment: @CommonsWare are there any more details you can provide about `our activity is being called into from an outside party`? Also is there a resource you recommend to garnering a deeper understanding of android? It's still not really clear to me how onCreate() is a callback.

Comment: "It's still not really clear to me how onCreate() is a callback" -- you are not calling `onCreate()` yourself. Hence, it is a callback. I don't really know how else to explain it. "Also is there a resource you recommend to garnering a deeper understanding of android?" -- if you mean a deeper understanding of how to write Android apps, there are [books](https://commonsware.com/Android). If you mean a deeper understanding of how Android itself works, there are [books](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do).