# How to notify when come back Fragment Android

Tags: android, fragment, back

In my case have two fragment first one FragmentA and second is FragmentB in FragmentA when click button call

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayoutGallery,myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

then show FragmentB , after in the second Fragment (FragmentB) button click call

```
int backStackId = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(backStackId,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

after that it will show FragmentA content but how to catch isShow FragmentA exactly ??

Comment: Would you prefer to use a library?

https://github.com/Trendyol/medusa

or 

https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use could use backstack listener in your case

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener{

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    try {
        Fragment tempFragment = 
               fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.view_container);
        if (tempFragment instanceof FragmentA)
            ((FragmentA) tempFragment).callThisMethod();
        else if (tempFragment instanceof FragmentB)
            //do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: can i do something in the FragmentA?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use callback , see this URL :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054720/what-is-callback-in-android#:%7E:text=In%20Android%20Callbacks%20are%20used,call%20methods%20in%20the%20Activity.)